# SQL finding the state with the most vendors with balance due

Tags: sql

I'm trying to develop a SQL query to find the state which has the most vendors with a balance due. Below is my work. I get this error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'WI' to data type int." Am I coding it correctly? Please help. Thanks!

```
SELECT VendorState, InvoiceTotal
    FROM Invoices JOIN Vendors ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
    WHERE VendorState > ALL
        (SELECT COUNT(InvoiceTotal)
        FROM Invoices JOIN Vendors ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
        WHERE VendorState > 1)
```

Comment: Post some sample input and desired output.

Comment: and schema as well

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT VendorState, SUM(InvoiceTotal)
FROM Invoices i JOIN
     Vendors v
     ON i.VendorID = v.VendorID
GROUP BY VendorState
ORDER BY SUM(InvoiceTotal) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

This is ANSI standard SQL.  Specific databases (and you don't specify the database) might have slightly different syntax -- although the idea is he same.